# how to refer variables in JSON file?

Tags: python, json, variables

I have following JSON data which I'm trying to use in python.

```
{"tag": "currency",
         "patterns": ["What is dollar rate in PKR", "Convert Dollar to PKR", "Convert USD to PKR", "What is Euro rate", "Convert Euro to PKR", "GBP rate in PKR", "British Pound Rate in PKR"],
         "currencies": ["Dollar", "USD", "US Dollar", "Euro", "Pound", "British Pound", "GBP"],
         "responses": [""],

        "context_filter": ""
        },
```

Also below is my python script:

```
  if i['tag'] == 'currency':
     if i['currencies'] == 'USD' :
        engine.say(data.USD_PKR)
     if i['currencies'] == 'pound':
        engine.say('I can\'t tell about Pound Yet')
```

What I want to do is making this script check two conditions:

**1:** It checks if the tag is matched (*i.e Currency*)

**2:** It checks the currency names from currency names.

My python chatbot reads the data from this json file. I want the chatbot to tell me currency rates to 'PKR' which is currency of my country.
the 'patterns' are basically the questions which user will ask from the chatbot.
I can write code to get currency rates of above mentioned currencies

**But** I can't figure out how to write a code so that it tells me rate of only that currency which I asked it in command line. 
For example:

**Me:** What is USD rate?

**Bot:** 105.4 PKR

**Me:** What is GBP rate?

**Bot:** 110.66 PKR

**Me:** What is Euro rate?

**Bot:** 125.3 PKR

I can get the conversion rates one by one, by scrapping a website and printing the results to command line. So that part is done.
I need to modify the Questions data so whenever a currency is mentioned in question, python script finds the rate for that particular currency which is mentioned in the Question.
Hope I have explained it correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `patterns` and `currencies` are both lists of data, so you will not be able to directly compare them to a string. Instead, you would need to loop through them or use something like `if "test" in i['currencies']:`. Beyond this, I am not really sure what your question is/what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am not sure what you question is... Also I am unsure what you really want to do. If you want to use the dict to convert currencies then you should store the conversion rates in it. If you just want to return what you could do with the data I do not know what you need from us since a lot of content is already in the dict...

Comment: @BrandonM I have edited the question. please take  a look at this now, if you don't mind.
 Does it make sense now?

Comment: @mrCarnivore In simple words, I want my bot to find rate for a currency  which I ask it to find. 
I have edited the question. Hope it makes my point clear.

Comment: Even as edited, the question doesn't show where your data is intended to come from. And, frankly, this is rather far from being a [mcve] -- if the question is about how to parse JSON, why do we need to know that you're building a chatbot *at all*? (For that matter, if your JSON is already converted to a native Python data structure, why do we need to know that the values were JSON before that conversion?). This would be greatly helped by identifying an *extremely specific* question, and removing any/every element not related to that specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regexp:

```
import re

question = input('What do you want to do?')
currency_to_convert =  re.findall('What is (\S*)', question, re.S)
print (*currency_to_convert)
```

Will print out the currency you want to know the rate from...

Comment: Are you encouraging someone to use a regexp *to parse JSON*?

Comment: No! I am encouraging someone to parse the user input with regexp to use the result to access the JSON/dict...

Comment: That makes sense. I'm not clear that it's what they're asking, though -- the title certainly implies that the question is about looking up data in their previously-JSON data structure, as does the code they provide. If the question text indicates that the question is *really* about parsing English prose in the chatbot, that's rather well-buried (and the OP should really center the title around it and remove everything that isn't directly related to that goal from their question).

Comment: That's what I asked in the comment under the question... Without placing the currency conversion rate in the JSON/dict I can't help in accessing it. That is why I think now after the question was rephrased that the question really is about knowing which currency to know the conversion from... I might be wrong, though. The question is not clear.